# How do I turn off safe mode while it also blocks me from logging in with a domain account?

Tags: windows-7, windows-domain, safe-mode

There is a machine that we log in to with only windows domain user accounts that can be used across different machines on our network. I tried to restart into safe mode using msconfig without thinking. Now I cannot log in to it because the windows domain service has not been started. Is there a way to turn off safe mode without logging in?

The exact error message is "An attempt was made to logon, but the network logon service was not started"

I tried to press F8 and start into safe mode with networking but I was still not able to log in.

Comment: Why not restart the machine and let it boot into Windows normally? Am I misunderstanding the question? This doesn't appear to be a problem. Windows was started in Safe Mode, so restart it and let Windows boot normally.

Comment: Are you in a situation where you boot into safe-mode every time?

Answer (score 0):

Just reboot the computer and boot up normally so all services load and you can load into windows, or if you really need to be in safe-mode, log in using a local username/password.

If you don't know the login info from the local pc, boot into normal mode, then login with the domain administrator user so you can create a user locally to then reboot into safemode and login with that user.

Other than this we cannot help you, because your question is not making any sense. It would help if you add why you want to be in safe-mode.

Comment: I set diagnostic start up while logged in using ms config. I could not turn this off without logging in first. There was no way to log in with out a local user.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last comment, try the following.

Reboot the pc and hold F8. Choose boot using last known config. This should override ms-config's changes and boot normally.

Comment: Tried that and it doesn't work. The boot was successful so it will use that config. I just can't log in. In the end it requires a local user.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Windows 8.1. In that case:

- I'm holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> while pressing restart button `Settings > Power > Restart`.
- Windows shows the options - `Advanced Options` or so is the right one.
- After choosing that you can find the way to boot with another options - `Safe Mode with Networking` for example.